# Can't change the root view size of a xib file in code. iOS

Tags: ios, layout, xib

It is a topic that mentioned many times here but I can't find the solution for my case.

I have disabled the "**auto layout**" property for the nib file, but in code, when calling

```
self.UserInfoController.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 100);
```

only the first two paras take effect, that is, the top-left corner of the view can change. But the size of the view won't change at all.

Any more info needed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the size of root view of a xib unless you change the size of the xib itself. If you want to have multiple views inside a xib I suggest you create subviews inside the root view.

To change the size of the xib. You need to change the 'Simulated Size' value (in Size Inspector) from 'Fixed' to 'FreeForm' for your xib in the editor and then assign width and height values.

**I cannot upload the image as reference as I am not having enough reputation.

Comment: Does "to change the 'Simulated Size' value (in Size Inspector) from 'Fixed' to 'FreeForm'" means my xib can't be adaptive to difference size iPhones?

Comment: In my code I changed the view controller size using following code

`if(IS_IPHONE)
{
 logoutController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(125, 40);
}`

IS_IPHONE is a macro i created to check if app is running on iPhone